# How do I play a sound in Python?

Tags: python

I was wondering is there anyway I could play a sound without importing an external library like pygame. Something like this:

```
import os    
import sound

mysound = sound.load("mysound.mp3") # gets the sound "mysound.mp3"

while True:    
        input("Press enter to play sound")    
        sound.play(mysound) # plays the sound mysound        
        os.system('cls') # clears the console
```

Comment: You can find answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804366/playing-mp3-files-with-python)

Comment: It is quite contrived and probably not what you meant, but you can use: print "\a" to make a sound.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. You need some library.

Answer (score 1):

The standard library has some functions for playing `.wav` files (see [`winsound.PlaySound`](http://docs.python.org/library/winsound.html#winsound.PlaySound) on Windows and the slightly outdated [`ossaudiodev`](http://docs.python.org/library/ossaudiodev.html) for Linux), but AFAIK no methods for loading `.mp3` files.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307305/play-a-sound-with-python) has several answers listing various third-party modules for playing sound.