# Play the contents of a sound retrieved from an url?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, wave, pyaudio

I am retrieving the sound from:

> http://translate.google.com/translate_tts

and writing it to a WAV file, when i double-click the file the sound plays ok, but when i use the WAVE module from python to open it, it gives me this error:

> wave.Error: file does not start with RIFF id

I want to know if there is a way for openning this file, or if it is possible to play the sound without writing it before.

Here is the relevant code:

```
url = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=%s&q=%s" % (lang, text)
hrs = {"User-Agent":
       "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7"}

request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers = hrs)
page = urllib.request.urlopen(request)

fname = "Play"+str(int(time.time()))+".wav"
file = open(fname, 'wb')
file.write(page.read())
file.close()
```

And the code that reads this file is:

```
INPUT_FRAMES_PER_BLOCK = 1024

wf = wave.open(fname, 'r')

pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = pa.open(format=pa.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                 channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                 rate=wf.getframerate(),
                 output=True)

data = wf.readframes(INPUT_FRAMES_PER_BLOCK)

while data != '':
    stream.write(data)
    data = wf.readframes(INPUT_FRAMES_PER_BLOCK)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

pa.terminate()
```

Thanks in advance!
I am using Python 3 BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this error because you're trying to play a file that isn't a `WAV`.

The sound generated by Google Translate is encoded as an `MP3`.

As for how to play an `MP3` sound with Python, I'd recommend you read [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804366/playing-mp3-files-with-python).

(Basically you have to install some library like [Pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/))

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you want a wav file, you could install something to convert it to a wav file. Pymedia is a good module for that. The pymedia version made for current versions of python could be difficult to find, however, I have found a good place to get it at: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pymedia

Here is a function that will convert the mp3 file to a wav file, and save a wav file in your file system:

```
def dumpWAV( name ):
    import pymedia.audio.acodec as acodec
    import pymedia.muxer as muxer
    import time, wave, string, os
    name1= str.split( name, '.' )
    name2= string.join( name1[ : len( name1 )- 1 ] )
    # Open demuxer first
    dm= muxer.Demuxer( name1[ -1 ].lower() )
    dec= None
    f= open( name, 'rb' )
    snd= None
    s= " "
    while len( s ):
        s= f.read( 20000 )
        if len( s ):
            frames= dm.parse( s )
            for fr in frames:
                if dec== None:
                    # Open decoder
                    dec= acodec.Decoder( dm.streams[ 0 ] )
                r= dec.decode( fr[ 1 ] )
                if r and r.data:
                    if snd== None:
                        snd= wave.open( name2+ '.wav', 'wb' )
                        snd.setparams( (r.channels, 2, r.sample_rate, 0, 'NONE','') )
                    snd.writeframes( r.data )
```

You may want to just play the mp3, but it is significantly easier to play a wav file in python. For example, pygame's support of mp3 files is limited, but it can always play a wav file.