# Play mp3 file not using default output (playback) device in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, audio, pyaudio

I know that on PyAudio it is possible to choose on what playback device to stream on but PyAudio doesnt support mp3 files. My script would work if one of the following problem was solved:

1. Play mp3 file on PyAudio
2. Convert from mp3 to wav without without any data loss and without PyDub (with [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20722321/6296626) of converting, I found out that in a longer audio, the ends are missing)
3. Somehow play sound from a mp3 file to different playback device (the device is not a default one)

Personally I want to solve the first problem.

I would be grateful if I can play mp3 file on PyAudio without any data loss or quality loss.

**EDIT:** I found out that when I play my mp3 file (which is btw a file generated from Google Text To Speech) with PyMedia, the endings also gone missing for some strange reason so perhaps the converting method (point 2.) is working correctly but the problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: Have you tried anything else besides PyAudio? You might find this answer helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26759539/295246

Comment: @HEADLESS_0NE I already saw that answer (I did a research). The point is I couldn't find anything written about playing sound on other playback devices. On my own I discovered a method at PyAudio to choose from which playback device I want the sound to play from.

Comment: That's great! You can post your solution has an answer to your own question. Perhaps it'll help someone with the same problem later on.

Comment: @HEADLESS_0NE sorry bad english, you misunderstand, I meant I already saw that post. With PyAudio I can manage to choose playback device but PyAudio cant read mp3 file (or so I think). On the other hand I can easily play the mp3 file with other library but I cant choose on which playback device it will play

Comment: Take a look in pymedia module this can play mp3 using pyaudio, if do you have some doubt i can try show for you how to do ...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329061/play-the-contents-of-a-sound-retrieved-from-an-url/20722321#20722321) you mentioned in your answer is about `pymedia` and not `pydub`.

Next, I've converted many files from `mp3` to `wav` using `pydub` without issues.

If you want to give it a try, here is an one liner code to covnert from `mp3` to `wav`. You will be able to use rest of your code this way using option-2.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
AudioSegment.from_file("audio.mp3", format="mp3").export("audio.wav", format="wav")
```

Comment: Yes I know. I just didn't want to use Pydub so I wrote "AND without PyDub". Anyway I didn't want to use PyDub because it requires to have ffmpeg installed and I am trying to avoid having my script depend on another software.