# Increase volume before streaming with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, audio, volume, pyaudio

Here we have a normal code for streaming audio from a wav file with PyAudio:

```
def play_sound(sound):
CHUNK = 1024
wf = wave.open(sound, 'rb')
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                rate=wf.getframerate(),
                output=True)
data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
while len(data) > 0:
    stream.write(data)
    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
return True
```

How do you increase volume to the audio before streaming it to speaker WITHOUT using PyDub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using the [soundfile](http://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/) and [sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/) modules?

```
import soundfile as sf
import sounddevice as sd

weight = 1.7

data, fs = sf.read('myfile.wav')
sd.play(data * weight, fs, blocking=True)
```

Comment: No, it won't do. It works but I use PyAudio for a reason. Is there someway to merge this with the PyAudio code?

Comment: What's the reason if I may ask?

Comment: I want to stream the audio to a playback device that is not default so with PyAudio I can use `output_device_index= ` to determine which playback device I want the audio to stream in. Also there are handy function like `get_device_info_by_index()` and `get_device_count()`.

If you know another way to stream an audio to a playback device that is not default, feel free to answer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277687/play-mp3-file-not-using-default-output-playback-device-in-python).

Comment: With `sounddevice` you can use `device=` with either the device number or with space-separated substrings. You can also use `sounddevice.default.device` to set a default for subsequent calls. To get the available devices and their IDs, you can use [query_devices()](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#sounddevice.query_devices). It's all in [the docs](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/), you should read them!

Comment: Thank you really much. I didn't notice when I quickly run through the documentation that there is option for `device=` in sounddevice.play(). It not only solve my problem but also shorten my code.