# libSDL2-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-libraries, sdl-2

I'm trying to build the SDL library from the  [source code](http://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php). I've downloaded the compressed file (i.e. `SDL2-2.0.3.tar.gz`) and extracted it. I don't want to install the files in `/usr/local`. According to [this link](https://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation), I need to change the `configure`

> The last command says "sudo" so we can write it to /usr/local (by
>   default). You can change this to a different location with the
>   --prefix option to the configure script. In fact, there are a LOT of good options you can use with configure! Be sure to check out its
>   --help option for details.

This is what I've done.

```
mkdir build
cd build
../configure
make
sudo make install
```

In `install` folder that I've created are the following files

```
share 
lib
include 
bin
```

Now I would like to run the test files. I've picked this `testatomic.c` and this is the command line 
`gcc testatomic.c -o test -I/home/xxxx/Desktop/SDL2-2.0.3/install/include/SDL2 -L/home/xxxx/Desktop/SDL2-2.0.3/install/lib -lSDL2 -lSDL2main`

I get this error

`error while loading shared libraries: libSDL2-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

In `lib`, these are the files

[image]

Where is the shared object file?

Comment: It is possible that it is attempting to link against the static library and finding the dynamic library.

I would try to link again after removing all the .a files and doing a clean build.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're getting error when running resulting program because system's dynamic linker cannot find required library. Program requires `libSDL2-2.0.so.0`, linker looks for it in system-defined directories (`/lib`, `/usr/lib`, ..., - defined in `/etc/ld.so.conf`), but finds none - hence an error.

To inform linker where you want it to look for libraries, you can define `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, e.g. in your case:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/Desktop/SDL2-2.0.3/install/lib"
./test
```

Other ways is installing libraries in standard location, defining LD_LIBRARY_PATH in your .bashrc (or whatever shell you use), or using rpath, e.g. adding `-Wl,-rpath=$HOME/Desktop/SDL2-2.0.3/install/lib` at the end of your compilation line.

Comment: I've placed the files in the same folder of the executable file but still no luck. There is a black arrow in the icon of the .os file. What does that mean? Is it shortcut?

Comment: As it should be - current directory isn't in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, linker wouldn't look here. Arrow means symbolic link - both links pointing to `libSDL2-2.0.so.2.1`

Comment: but my whole point of compiling from source code is to have flexibility for moving the files. This is trivial in Windows but I thought the process will be much simpler in Linux.

Comment: Then your point was wrong. Compiling from sources changes nothing, you can do whatever you like with binary libraries too. It only requires to know what you're doing. For security reasons, LD_LIBRARY_PATH (as well as PATH) doesn't include `.` (current working directory). Usually if your software requires to link with libraries distributed with it, you need to create a shell script that sets appropriate env variables and launches your software; that's how maya, steam and almost everyone else doing it. Windows approach considered insecure here.

Answer (score 9):

I was able to fix this problem with:

```
sudo apt install libsdl2-dev
```

Comment: Similar with me but I didn't install the development files: `apt-get install libsdl2-2.0-0`

Answer (score 2):

I too had:

> ./01_hello_SDL: error while loading shared libraries: libSDL2-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

as a result of compiling the first C++ program (using the SDL headers) as part of the Lazy Foo tutorial. I found out that libSDL2-2.0.so.0 was just using the find command in the GUI. It turned out to be in `/usr/local/lib`

Then in terminal I typed:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib"
```

I checked the value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` using:

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I recompiled (don't know if that was necessary) and voila, it worked.