# How to Play a Mp3 file using Python in Windows?

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I have tried playing file using Pygame
This is the following code:

```
    import time, sys
    from pygame import mixer
    # pygame.init()
    mixer.init()

   sound = mixer.Sound("C:\Users\sharathchandra\Downloads\17.wav")
   sound.play()

   time.sleep(5)
```

But it does not throw any error but the song is not played.
I tried playing .wav files but with the same result
I also tried pyglet 
But it shows >WAVEFormatException: AVbin is required to decode compressed media
I would like to learn how to install  AVbin 
I have run the codes using spyder on Windows and my python version is 2.7.
I have also run many examples of pygame but no use.
I want to Learn a correct way for Playing the mp3 files using Python and How to install the Desired Library For that Purpose.

Comment: Make sure the WAV file is encoded properly. There's many different formats for it, so go on the pygame wiki and check which one is proper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this (solution taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20021547/2204926)):

```
mixer.music.load('C:\Users\sharathchandra\Downloads\17.wav') # you may use .mp3 but support is limited
mixer.music.play()
```

**Many** more ways can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260738/play-audio-with-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307305/play-a-sound-with-python).

Also, you might want to read the [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html) on Pygame's music.

Comment: I Tried that Code Before The code throws no error But not able to hear any sound.

Comment: Are you sure the file is at that location and your speakers are up? If so, try the other ways I have linked.

Comment: Yeah with the Help of  Os module's Play function.

Answer (score 1):

```
'''
Created on 2016. 6. 6.
This module is for playing a mp3 file by using pygame module
@author: Peter Sun
'''

import pygame

filePath = r"C:\learn\***.mp3"    #change to your MP3 file path

def playmusic(filename):
    BUFFER = 3072
    pygame.mixer.init()
    FREQ, SIZE, CHAN = pygame.mixer.get_init()
    pygame.mixer.init(FREQ, SIZE, CHAN, BUFFER)
    pygame.init()
    pygame.mixer.init()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    pygame.mixer.music.load(filename)


    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    while True:
        clock.tick(500)
        print clock

try:

    playmusic(filePath)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    print("User soptted music")
except Exception:
    print("Unknown error")

print "Done!"
```

Comment: This answer seems to have a bunch of extra code that doesn't directly answer the question, such as the clock stuff.  I would try to minimize this to just what you need to load and play a .wav file.

Comment: this file was only trying to open a mp3 file. According the title, the code is for a mp3 file. You can get rid of the clock thing if you don't want it. it shows fps dynamically to monitor wave of audio file.

Comment: Thank you so much your solution worked perfectly and i think the clock stuff prevents the console from closing down right?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [VLC Python module](https://wiki.videolan.org/Python_bindings), vlc.py, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25899180/5861350):

```
import vlc
p = vlc.MediaPlayer("file:///path/to/track.mp3")
p.play()
```

And you can stop it with:

```
p.stop()
```

Comment: Can you specify how to install the vlc module?

Comment: Download `vlc.py` from [their git repository](https://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=blob;f=generated/3.0/vlc.py;h=025331241e25bd6b39a6ede8a7a6b022d390ed6f;hb=HEAD)

Put the file in the same place as your script and import it with `import vlc`