# I want to play a sound ( a song from my computer,preferred) on completion of my python program

Tags: python, git, module, web-crawler

First of all, I am new to python.
I am trying to make a web crawler that keeps keeps checking a particular website until it finds a specific tv series keywords available.

I have gone through the other answers many times by now, but nothing works for me.
I am unable to install pygame as suggested here:- [Playing mp3 song on python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021457/playing-mp3-song-on-python)

Tried importing the the webbrowser, installing vlc module from git, things dont work out.

Can someone just give me a simple detailed guide to do this?

Comment: You want to play the song inside the python or open the song file?

Comment: I am using pycharm , jetbrains ide , OS is windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the song 'your_song.mp3' is stored in your computer in the directory '/Users/', you can open the song from your python program doing this:

```
import subprocess 

subprocess.Popen(['open','/Users/your_song.mp3'])
```

Note: the previous code will work on OS X. For windows, type instead:

```
subprocess.Popen(['start','/Users/your_song.mp3'],shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on a `*nix` based system, here is a simple example using the `python` standard library.

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> import subprocess
>>> url = 'http://example.com/'
>>> req = urllib.request.Request(url)
>>> data = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
>>> data
<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x7f483018be80>
>>> html_data = data.read()
>>> ## replace it with your logic
>>> your_case_here = True
>>> if your_case_here:
...   subprocess.run(["gnome-open", "/path/to/mo3_file/hello.mp3", "/dev/null"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
... else:
...   pass
>>>
```