# Python MP3 Player

Tags: python, mp3, playback

I Am Trying To Play An MP3 File On Python , But I Can't Find The Right Module!
I've Tried This:

```
import os
os.startfile('hello.mp3')
```

But I Just Got The **Error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Youtube/text 2 speech/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    os.startfile('hello.mp3')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'startfile'
```

I Have Also Tried This:

```
import vlc
p = vlc.MediaPlayer("file:hello.mp3")
p.play()
```

But I Get The **Error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Youtube/text 2 speech/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import vlc
ImportError: No module named 'vlc'
```

But I Still Can't Find The Right Module. Could Someone Please Help?

Comment: What Happened When You Tried Either Of Those Things?

Comment: And is there some error message? Does a player start but no music is heard? What is your operating system? Try to be a bit more specific, otherwise we cannot really help! Also, see [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Just check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021457/playing-mp3-song-on-python

Comment: my operating system is Os X Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: My favourite for this task is pyglet

Comment: Linux, mac or windows?

Comment: My Computer Is A Mac.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the `vlc.py` module from https://wiki.videolan.org/Python_bindings

The absolute bare bones for this would be something like:

```
import vlc
Inst = vlc.Instance()
player = Inst.media_player_new()
Media = Inst.media_new_path('/home/rolf/vp1.mp3')
player.set_media(Media)
player.play()
```

Although you would need to check `player.get_state()` to see if it is still running, paused, stopped etc and `player.stop()` to stop the audio once started

As far as I am aware `os.startfile()` is only available for the `windows` operating system.
Using the `play` command line instruction (Linux and probably OS X)

```
import os
os.system('play /home/rolf/vp1.mp3')
```

You could also look at Gstreamer, although the documentation could do with some improvement.

```
import gst
player = gst.element_factory_make("playbin")
player.set_property("uri", "file:///home/james/vp1.mp3")
player.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)
```

play is stopped with `player.set_state(gst.STATE_NULL)`,
pause with `player.set_state(gst.STATE_PAUSED)`

Note: Avoid tutorials for Gstreamer version 0.10, search instead for version 1.0
Both `vlc` and `Gstreamer` allow you to play audio and video, although, in my opinion, `vlc` in simpler to use but `Gstreamer` is more flexible.

Comment: os.system is really, really old fashioned, proposed depricated.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Indeed but it beats `os.startfile('hello.mp3')` hands down! ;)

Comment: For straightforward use, on all platforms, there are better alternatives.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I'm simply answering the OP's specific question. If you have an opinion, state it but state it to the OP and not to me. I am already aware of the range of alternatives.

Comment: I Have Downloaded vlc.py And Put It In The Dictionary Of The Py File.

Comment: It' s easiest if you put vlc.py in the same directory as your program file, especially as I don't know what you mean by "The Dictionary Of The Py File"

Answer (score 0):

import pygame
from pygame import mixer

def play_music():
global paused

```
if (paused):
    mixer.music.unpause()
    paused = False
else:
    music = choose_music[0]
    mixer.music.load(music)
    mixer.music.play()
    show_details(music)
    musicpage.mainloop()
```