# Python Play mp3 File

Tags: python, audio, speech-recognition

```
from gtts import gTTS
import os
import subprocess
tts = gTTS(text='Hello World', lang='en') //TEXT TO SPEECH
tts.save("audio.mp3") //Hello world will be saved in audio.mp3
os.system("mpg321 audio.mp3") <-- I want to play the audio file in python(not to call any other music player)
```

I want to play the audio.mp3 file, but nothing happnes (cmd comes up and goes away in 1 second)

Comment: The command name is mpg123, not mp321. And it only exists on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to be fine; I can repeat it on my system except that I don't have the application mpg321 installed so I use `play` from the `sox` family instead and it works correctly even without a full path to the file name.

See if you have `sox` installed on your machine, and if so try playing the file with `play` which will be able to pick up the parameters of the mp3 from the file. Alternatively use a different player, but be careful to use one that can read mp3 files properly otherwise you will get a blast from the loudspeakers.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify the absolute path to your mp3 file. (like `C:/songs/song.mp3`)

Also, consider using pygame if it won't work. Have you tried a solution from this question? [Playing mp3 song on python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021457/playing-mp3-song-on-python)