# Play, Loop, and Fade mp3s in Python 3.6

Tags: python, macos, audio, mp3

I'm creating a small game (adapting already existing code, not using pygame) and I want it to have background music. Ideally, I would be able to pause, loop, and fade the music if necessary. I'm running python 3.6 on a Mac, but it would be optimal if this worked on Windows too.

Answers to similar questions have made reference to things like PIP, and PyPi. I'm a novice so I don't know what those are. If you could tell me what to do from the beginning that would be great!

Comment: why don't you want to use pygame? There's an easy way to play music with pygame: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021457/playing-mp3-song-on-python

Comment: I'm happy to use pygame for music! I'm just not using it for the game itself.