# Open MP3 sound file from python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, vlc

I have VLC installed on my raspberry pi 3. I want to be able to run a python file that opens a mp3 sound file (my_sound.mp3) and plays the sound. The closest that I got is:

```
import os
import subprocess
os.system("/usr/bin/cvlc")
```

Rasp is running  ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Playing mp3 song on python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021457/playing-mp3-song-on-python)

Comment: @Martin: fyi, your actions [are being discussed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379138/told-i-would-only-get-correct-answer-if-i-accepted-incorrect-one)

Answer (score -2):

Well, I fixed the issue:

```
apt-get install mpg321


import os
os.system('mpg321 mysoung.mp3 &')
```

if you want to loop use the following key:

```
os.system('mpg321 -l 0 mysoung.mp3 &')
```