# How to close the .mp3 file in Text to Speech as show in the details?

Tags: text-to-speech

In the above code I am able to convert the text 'Hello world' in the speech but how to close the .mp3 that is created. os.remove will not work until that .mp3 file is closed. 
Please suggest.

I am trying text to speech functionality

```
import os 
from gtts import gTTS

myobj = gTTS(text='Hello world', lang="en", slow=False) 

myobj.save("audio1.mp3")

os.startfile('audio1.mp3')
```

## What I expect is audio1.mp3 should be closed.

Comment: You can probably skip `os.startfile` line, so it will never open it.

Comment: If I skip os.startfile then my audio will not play.

Comment: There are other ways of playing the file with more control on what is going on - pygame, vlc, etc. You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021457/playing-mp3-song-on-python