# Is there any Python module to play all .mp3 files in a directory?

Tags: python-3.x, audio, module, directory, mp3

I would like to play all the mp3 files one by one in a directory using python, is there any module that will help me out to perform the task

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the [`pygame`](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted) package. It lets you play MP3s.

Building off [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021457/playing-mp3-song-on-python), you could do something like

```py
from time import sleep
from pathlib import Path  # for directory listing
import pygame

DIRECTORY = Path('./path/to/your/directory')
mixer.init()

for fp in DIRECTORY.glob('*.mp3'):
    # add each file to the queue
    mixer.music.load(str(fp))
    mixer.music.play()

    # now wait until the song is over
    while mixer.music.get_busy():
        sleep(1)  # wait 1 second
```

Note that the order of `glob()` isn't controlled here, so you may want to introduce your own sorting/ordering.

Comment: Thank you for the code, but your snippets are throughing some errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python ffmpeg (https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg-python/)

use a loop to check for all files in the directory and use ffmpeg to play the mp3 file.

https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

lists_of_songs = os.listdir("/path/to/the/directory")

for song in lists_of_songs:
    if song.endswith(".mp3"):
        file_path = "/path/to/the/directory/" + song
        pygame.mixer.music.load(str(file_path))
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        print("Playing::::: " + song)
        while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
            continue
```