# How to play all the files in a playlist of mp3 files?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a directory which contains `.mp3` and `.ini` files I want my program to select all the files with `.mp3` and play them. Not as separate files but all at once means that when normally you select a few songs and play, it would create a playlist inside your default player. I want to do that.

Any help would be appreciated

Note from comment:

I know how to list all of the items. What I want to know is how to play all of them so that it creates a playlist of them so that when the first one finishes the second one automatically plays.

or How can i enter a folder click ctrl a and hit enter without it actually showing on the screen?

This could solve my problem

Comment: [Playing mp3 song on python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021457/playing-mp3-song-on-python)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) library.

```py
from glob import glob
files = glob("/home/some_folder/*.mp3")
print(files)
```

Comment: @ArjunBasandrai Did you try the solution? Did it help?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create .m3u files iteratively, it looks something like this

```
/home/songs/01.mp3
/home/songs/02.mp3
/home/songs/03.mp3
```

And then simply play .m3u files