# Playing sound in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to play a `.mp3` file.

My code :

```
import os

os.system("start C:\Users\User\Desktop\Wakeup.mp3")
```

But, it gives an error like this:

```
File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Test.py", line 2
    os.system("start C:\Users\User\Desktop\Wakeup.mp3")
             ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 8-9: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

with other variants for playing a sound, I'm getting the same error

Thanks for attention

Comment: Take a look at this to get more insight into how to use it... https://pythonbasics.org/python-play-sound/

Comment: You might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021457/playing-mp3-song-on-python.

Answer (score 2):

You did not escape the backslash character. try this:

```
os.system("start C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Wakeup.mp3")
```

**Option 2**

Use forward slash instead:

```
os.system("start C:/Users/User/Desktop/Wakeup.mp3")
```

**Option 3**

Use "raw" string:

```
os.system(r"start C:\Users\User\Desktop\Wakeup.mp3")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play sound. You can do something like this.

```
from playsound import playsound

playsound("path/name.mp3")
```

Hope this helps ... :D