# Play MP3 on Linux from Python

Tags: linux, audio

I just want to play a simple MP3 file on Linux directly from the Python code.

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260738/play-audio-with-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021457/playing-mp3-song-on-python) question and tried the following libraries but all of them failed: `audioplayer`, `Ipython.display.Audio`, `pydub`, `pygame.mixer`, `ossaudiodev`, `soundfile`.

Errors that I saw often were:

- `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'`
- Errors with `ffmpeg`

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'` sounds as if it you were simply missing a dependency -- for ubuntu / debian, check this out: [What would cause the “gi” module to be missing from Python?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80448/what-would-cause-the-gi-module-to-be-missing-from-python) "Errors with ffmpeg" is way too vague, but I'd guess this may also have to do with wrong / missing dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pyglet` is the only solution I found that can play MP3 on Linux:

```
import pyglet
sound = pyglet.media.load("/home/max/Desktop/sound.mp3")
sound.play()
```

[Source](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/491663/how-to-open-and-play-mp3-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

There is a bunch of ways!

Try the `vlc` python module?

```
import vlc

file = vlc.MediaPlayer("example.mp3")
file.play()
```

You can also stop it with `file.stop()`

Since `mp3` is not supported by some of the 'better' audio module you may also wanna convert it to `wav`. You could play and convert with `pydub`

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

file = AudioSegment.from_mp3("example.mp3")
file.export("new.wav", format="wav")
```

Answer (score 0):

[MPV.io](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpv_(media_player)) would be a good one.  Lightweight media player that plays just about anything you throw at it.  [Python-MPV](https://github.com/jaseg/python-mpv) to access features.

Has methods for playlists, if you want to do an entire directory.  They also include directions for multiple GUI's;  GTK, QT, be easy enough to use filedialog from TK.