# why does pygame mixer can't play song at runtime

Tags: python, pygame

I have an array of Song class objects that I created and I'm having problem playing music with pygame mixer.

[image: photo]

as you can see, I have 4 songs in the working directory, I created an array of Songs object which have information about the different song.
on particular function that I have created is `getIndexName()` which returns the name of the file.
the name of the array is `songsData`.

If I would call the function:
`mixer.music.load("song1.mp3)` and then `mixer.music.play()`
it works fine, however if I would call:
`mixer.music.load(songsData[1].getIndexName())` and then `mixer.music.play()`

I'm getting an error:

> ```
> mixer.music.load(songsData[1].getIndexName())
> pygame.error: Couldn't open 'song2.mp3
> ```

I think that I have to determine which file I want to play at compilation time, but I don't know If I think right.
If I'm right is there any module that can play mp3 files (or wav) and I can determine which file at run-time? (like calling random).

thanks for youre help!

Comment: Python is not a compiled language

Comment: Make sure the song2.mp3 file is there

Comment: Try to include the absolute path to the song file

Comment: Your songsData list is empty before it is called?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VLC module:

```
import vlc
p = vlc.MediaPlayer("file:///home/user/Music/song1.mp3")
p.play()
```

Or try https://stackoverflow.com/a/68964908/11844784

Comment: no need to fight guys!
Same issue with vlc.. if Im writing the name of the file it works but if im getting the name from function it doesn't work

Comment: @omerap12 Make sure the file is actually there or that there aren't any typos in your file names.

Comment: I checked, file there and no typos

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68964908/11844784