# The "startfile()" function is not working in Python 3.9.7

Tags: python, batch-file, vbscript

I wanted to build a script playing an audio file in the background, so i found code on **Stack Overflow** to run an audio file without the window popping up:

```
@echo off
set file=song.mp3
( echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
  echo Sound.URL = "%file%"
  echo Sound.Controls.play
  echo do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
  echo wscript.sleep 100
  echo loop
  echo wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000) >sound.vbs
start /min sound.vbs
```

When i ran the file in File Explorer, it worked perfectly.

But my main goal is to get a **Python script** (.py file) to run it for me without having any visuals, so i tried calling the `startfile()` function from the **os module** in my python file, like this:

```
import os
from locate import this_dir

path = str(this_dir())

os.startfile(path + "\\run_song.py")
```

This time, no errors were provided, but the sound couldn't be heard.

I use **Visual Studio Code** and **Python** 3.9.7

Here is the code inside "run_song.py":

```
from os import startfile
from locate import this_dir

path = str(this_dir())

startfile(path + "\\sound.vbs")
```

Here Are The Insides Of "sound.vbs":

```
Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")
Sound.URL = "song.mp3"
Sound.Controls.play
do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
wscript.sleep 100
loop
wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration)+1)*1000
```

Yes, i tried using the VLC module and it didn't work. This error popped up.

```
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\Dani\Desktop\Code\libvlc.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

Here Is The Principal File (run_song.py)'s code.

```
from locate import this_dir
import vlc

path = str(this_dir())

p = vlc.MediaPlayer("file:///" + path + "song.mp3")
p.play()
```

Comment: Show us the contents of `run_song.py`.

Comment: @John Gordon: Sure, Edited The Question To Show The Content.

Comment: Start with trying to make "run_song.py" work on its own

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the question.  In the first sentence, you say the audio file is run "silently".  Then you say that when this program is run, no sound is produced.  If you want sound, why are you running it silently?

Comment: `run_song.py` is missing a closing parenthesis.  Is that a typo?  Why are you running a python program to run a python program, to run a VBS file?

Comment: @Y.R.: I Can't, Both Of The Winsound/Playsound Modules Are Not Working For Me, And If I Post A Help Question Here, It Will Get Downvoted, And My Private Feedback Will Say: "There Are Other Answers On This Question" When These Use The Playsound/Winsound Modules (Which, As I Said, Does Not Work Correctly For Me). So I Need To Use A File For The Audio, A File To Run The Audio File (I Want To Use The File As My Python Script Is Running), Hope This Info I Clear Enough.

Comment: @John Gordon: Silently Means In The Background (Without Any Media Player)

Comment: @Mark Tolonen: I Don't Understand

Comment: The last line of run_song.py is missing a closing parenthesis, and Why Are You Capitializing Everything?  You show a python script that launches `run_song.py`, and `run_song.py` launches a `.vbs` file.  Why not just run "run_song.py"?

Comment: Show us the contents of `sound.vbs`.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen: First Question: That Was My Fault, I Copied The Code But I Didn't Copy The Ending Parenthesis, Second Question: I Try Forgetting That I Want To Capitalize, But Everytime I Write Something On The Computer, I Forget That I Do Not Want To Capitalize.

Comment: @John Gordon: Put The Contents Of "sound.vbs" In The Question.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Are You Sure? Then Why Are There No Errors In The Terminal?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: But I Am!

Comment: according to documentation, startfile exists in python 3.9 https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/os.html?highlight=os#module-os

Comment: @BugVVZero nvm my mistake

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Its Okay To Make Mistakes.

Comment: No, I Tells Me That libVLC Is Missing, I Updated My Question For It To Include My Code + Error

Answer (score 0):

os.startfile is not the function you are looking for. Take a look at the documentation:

> this acts like double-clicking the file in Windows Explorer, or giving the file name as an argument to the start command from the interactive command shell: the file is opened with whatever application (if any) its extension is associated.

In order to play music files, you can install vlc python library using

```
pip3 install python-vlc
```

And try this simple method:

```
import vlc
p = vlc.MediaPlayer("C:/path/to/file/file.mp3")
p.play()
```

(taken from [Playing mp3 song on python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021457/playing-mp3-song-on-python))

Comment: Got This Error: FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\Dani\Desktop\Code\libvlc.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

Comment: Updated Question With My Code + Error

Comment: Edited to be more accurate. Paths sometimes get annoying (mostly in windows).
take a look at os.path and pathlib. also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python

Comment: Do I Need To Install VLC Media Player To Use The Module?